# why RenderPage is not recognized?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

This is discouraging me - I'm using the latest version of .NET core, SDK, visual studio 2019,
Started new project - ASP.net core Razor pages, I'm tring to add `@RenderPage("")` without success.

It looks like it is not part of abstract class RazorPage (that inherit RazorPageBase, at the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor namespace (part of dotnet\packs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref\3.1.3\ref\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll))

Everything I try, there is an error that says:

> Error  CS0103  The name 'RenderPage' does not exist in the current context

my _Layout page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - TestApp</title>
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />*@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @RenderPage("/Shared/_MenubarPage")
    </div>
    <div class="container">

        
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

(Of course I have partial _MenubarPage.cshtml page within Shared folder)

Can anyone please tell me where am I doing wrong? Should I add some kind of an external nuget?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code snippet in (the asp.net core 3.1) _layout page.

```
<partial name="_MenubarPage" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@RenderPage("_MenubarPage.cshtml");`.

You can also use `@RenderPage("_MenuPage.cshtml", MyModel)` which allows you to supply any model you like to the view by including it as a second parameter.

You can also use     `@{Html.RenderPartial("_MenubarPage");}` if you are using a partial. But don't forget that you need to wrap it with the razor code block `@{}`

Comment: But, it's not about the method's arguments... It is the method itself that is not recognize by the framework. And everywhere I look on the web is useing this method, so, is it an old version of razor?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the the @RenderPage() inside @{}. Example: @{ RenderPage(_Menubarpage.cshtml) } ?  If you are using .NETCore 3.1 then you are using the latest and greatest. But to answer your question, yes, it is very possible the method you are seeing on the web is an older version of .NETCore.

Comment: Yes. I tried. Still the message I get -"The name 'RenderPage' does not exist in the current context". It's hard to believe that Microsoft would do changes in code without pointed it in MSDN....

Comment: <partial name="_MenubarPage" /> its worked for me in asp.net core 3.1. @user1731254